# iOS UICollectionView horizontal scroll, how to set the header to be scroll horizontal like the section in UITableView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on `UICollectionView` and I need to set the header as horizontal scroll like the emojie in the native keyboard.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

basically, you can't do it by Native Code.

But you can use this: https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

Comment: so how apple create the keyboard and the header section in the native keyboard

Comment: @houssamhammoud keyborad have a accessoryview.